# Fourier Descriptors with SVM Implementation for object class recognition based on shape

Tags: opencv, fft, svm, shapes, feature-descriptor

I want to classify images into two classes based on their shapes. For this I have used fourier descriptors with SVM  classifer. My problem is that length of fourier descriptor depends upon number of boundary points, hence length of descriptors of various images is different. But for training SVM I need the training matrix with descriptors as rows of matrix(cv::Mat).I am implementing it in c++ using  openCV.What should I do ? should I :
1.pad the remaining descriptors to length of longest descriptor with zeroes
2.sample only fixed number of points from boundary

Else suggest me the right way.

Comment: could you share what method you used for sampling a fix number of points and how well it worked?  For example, how did you chose which points to keep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach in this case is to sample a fixed number of points from the boundary, so that your input vectors are of equal length. Padding is a bad idea because by doing so you implicitly change the definition of distance between padded points and non-padded points.

Comment: Thanks Marc.I am having one more doubt.After application of dft on boundary points (x+jy x-real y-imaginary (x,y)-coordinates of boundary) what I am having is a double channel Mat that is Mat depicting complex values. But SVM takes only a single channel floating point matrix as training data.Should I take magnitude of complex number as the single channel real valued descriptor or should I copy the imaginary part of descriptors i.e.2nd channel into the first one doubling the column length of original mat and reducing 1 channel or what else I need to do?

Comment: "Rotation invariant of the FDs are achieved by ignoring the phase information and by taking only the magnitude values of the FDs." - as written in a research paper.   Does it imply that I just need to take magnitude of complex number descriptor values I am having which will also solve my problem of converting 2 channel cv::Mat to single channel for training SVM.

Comment: @user2442331 I don't know the specifics of your problem, but I guess that ignoring the complex part of your data is a bad idea. You could indeed use two inputs for each complex number as you suggest, or maybe go for magnitude+phase (2 inputs per complex number as well). With regards to the research paper: it all depends on its assumptions and applications. It's probably best to try both approaches and see what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks Marc.           If anyone newbie is planning to use fourier descriptors then this paper may be useful A Comparative Study on Shape Retrieval Using Fourier Descriptors with Different Shape Signatures
Dengsheng Zhang and Guojun Lu

Comment: @MarcClaesen I am using SVM with SURF , and i am getting error on descriptors training , because descriptors are of different size , and SVM need only one row for each image